# access to another XML file

Tags: java, android

I want to have an access to another XML file in an inner class but I can't get a reference to the other XML components, this an inner class code:

```
    class ItemsClass extends ArrayAdapter<String>
         {

    public ItemsClass ()
    {
        super(ListActivity.this, R.layout.itemslist);   
    }


    public View getView (final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //setContentView(R.layout.itemslist);
        final String s = this.getItem(position);
       LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflater();

       View  row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemslist, parent, false);


       // get ref to each component in itemList.xml
TextView itemName= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);// here i can't access to the TextView in itemslist.xml


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  View  row= inflator.inflate(R.layout.itemslist, null);
```

read this 
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are trying to using the same xml for both the main activity & the row component.I think you need to reiterate your code,check about the neccesity of the usage of the constructor here.Cheers.

Comment: no i use different xml for the activity and row components, BUT i couldn't find the id reference for the elements of row components xml file (i also see the R.java and there is no definition for the elements of row components xml  )